# Autocomplete suggestions for .gql file paths inside typescript files in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, graphql, next.js

We are enabling loading graphql files in a Client Side Next.js App. We are using graphql tag loader:

```js
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
    })

    return config
  },
```

It works just great. It gives back all the available countries. But the issue we have is that when you try to find a graphql file, it does not show you **autocomplete suggestions** while you are typing in VSCode even tho we have `queries/getCountries.gql`:

[image]

Comment: You'd need to write or find a TypeScript Server plugin that provides such functionality. There is a ts-server plugin for graphql: https://github.com/Quramy/ts-graphql-plugin, but it looks like it does not currently support such functionality. It looks like you're looking for something analogous to https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-css-modules. You can either go write this yourself, or politely ask someone else to and see if they'd be so kind as to do so, or pay someone to. I think asking someone on Stack Overflow to write one for you as an answer would be too broad of a question.